# Using a variable for an object property name in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, properties

Using this neat little plugin, http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit, very much like jQuery's built in support for:

```
$('.some-element').css({propname1: 'value1', propname2: 'value2'});
```

It works like so:

```
$('.some-element').transition({ x: '40px', y: '40px' });
```

and I can use variable for the property values like this (this works):

```
var xVal = '40px',
    yVal = '40px';
$('.some-element').transition({ x: xVal, y: yVal });
```

but I need to be able to specify the 'type' of transformation via a variable like so (this doesn't work):

```
<div class="some-element" data-ca-type1="x" data-ca-type2="y"></div>

var xVal = '40px',
    yVal = '40px',
    target = $('.some-element'),
    type1 = target.data('caType1'),
    type2 = target.data('caType2');
target.transition({ type1: xVal, type2: yVal });
```

Comment: NOTE: `var x-val` is a syntax error, you can't have a `-` in a variable name.

Comment: `class=".some-element"` should be `class="some-element"` so you can select it with `.`

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  What's the problem?  What happens, doesn't happen?  Do you see any errors in your console?  What is `caType1`?  Is that a variable, or did you mean `target.data('caType1')`?

Comment: no error, just doesn't perform the action, much like how .css may not throw an error in the console if the name/value isn't just right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[]` on arrays and objects to set dynamic property values.

```
transitionData = {};
transitionData[type1] = xVal;
transitionData[type2] = yVal;
target.transition(transitionData);
```

I tend to prefer to inline these sorts of things, which can be done by instantiating an anonymous function:

```
target.transition(new function () {
    this[type1] = xVal;
    this[type2] = yVal;
}());
```

Although generally I'd probably just keep the transition data directly in the `[data-*]` attribute as JSON, taking advantage of jQuery's auto-parsing with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<div data-ca='{"x":"40px","y":"40px"}'></div>
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('[data-ca]').each(function () {
    $(this).transition($(this).data('ca'));
});
```

Comment: This was by far the simplest method, thank you!  Oh man, I knew I should have asked earlier...would have saved me loads of time =)

Answer (score 0):

In an object literal, the property names are always literals. You need to use array syntax to create properties with calculated property names:

```
var x_val = '40px',
    y_val = '40px',
    target = $('.some-element'),
    type1 = target.data('caType1'),
    type2 = target.data('caType2'),
    options = {};
options[type1] = x_val;
options[type2] = y_val;
target.transition(options);
```

Comment: same as anthony, just needed to add the quotes around the data props, thx

Comment: @user1157601 Not fair, you changed the question after I posted my answer.

Comment: sorry Barmar, didn't change the question, just fixed some typos... your answer was identical to Anthonys and I tried to +1 your answer as useful but I don't have the needed rep yet

Comment: The question didn't have quotes around `caType1` and `caType2` when I wrote my answer, so how was I supposed to know those were typos? And where the values of `type1` and `type2` come from are immaterial to the question and answer. The answer you accepted doesn't even include those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an empty object (or an object with non-dynamic keys) first, then use the square bracket notation to set the values for the dynamic keys. Something like this:

```
var xVal = '40px',
    yVal = '40px',
    target = $('.some-element'),
    type1 = target.data(caType1),
    type2 = target.data(caType2);
var options = {}
options[type1] = xVal;
options[type2] = yVal;
target.transition(options);
```

When creating an object using the object literal syntax the keys are always treated as string values. `{x: 0}` is equivalent to `{"x": 0}` or `{'x': 0}`, so even if you have a variable `x` the JavaScript engine doesn't know that it's supposed to use the value of `x` rather than the string `"x"` as the key.

Comment: yep, same thing, no errors once I add '' around target.data('caType1'); but still doesn't apply the animation